# I was born a Hindu, and I continue. Is it against Allah's will that it is so?

Tags: free-will, freedom-of-belief

Do people take birth in other religions by Allah's will?

Is it by Allah's will that people of other religions exist in such large numbers?

Or is it against Allah's will that this state of affairs exists and continues?

Comment: It appears as though there's a more meaningful question behind this question. Perhaps you can rather ask about what led to this question?

Comment: @Shoaib - Kindly take the question at its face value and answer it if possible. If I need to ask another question (including another question that led to this question), I will ask separately.

Comment: I deleted my incoherent and overly theoretical answer. This video is better than all I could muster up: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Ar4cu5znTI

Comment: See also: "[How to answer those who says “Allah guides whom He wills” that's why I am not a believer?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11058/9123)"

Answer (score 1):

In Quran, [(Surah Maida - Chapter 5, Verse: 48)](http://quran.com/5/48) God has mentioned that

> ...Had Allah willed, He would have made you one nation [united in religion], but [He intended] to test you in what He has given you; so race to [all that is] good. To Allah is your return all together, and He will [then] inform you concerning that over which you used to differ.

So different religions are in complete accordance with His will. Rather, forcing everyone on a single religion is against His will

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter who your parent or family are. In Islam everyone is born a Muslim. Every baby you see is a Muslim however when some grow up and decide to follow other faiths when he knows Islam is right then he will be punished. Religion is not something that should be blindly followed by what your family follows but what the truth is. And of course everything happens by the will of Allah. People of other religions exist because Allah guides whom He wills.

Comment: "Every baby you see is a Muslim however when some grow up and decide to follow other faiths". Please elaborate on this a little.

Comment: Every person born is born a muslim so if a child dies they die a muslim. When they reach maturity and know the difference between wrong and right yet decide to chose another religion out if ignorance then they will be punished.

Comment: Ok, so although I think I was born a Hindu, I am really a Muslim. And even if I say I am a Hindu and not a Muslim, my whole family, including my parents, my wife and my children are really Muslims. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: If you have not reached puberty yes but otherwise no because you have chosen to follow something else.

Comment: Ok, so I was born a Muslim (albeit with a Hindu name and of Hindu parents), but in the month that I hit puberty, my position changed and I became a Hindu because I had "chosen Hinduism over Islam". Is that correct? 

In other words, with puberty, I had converted from Islam to Hinduism, and I am deemed to have chosen to follow the religion of my forefathers. Is that what you are saying?

Can you quote the correct Sura in favour of what you are saying here?

Comment: When you reached puberty you had matured and you knew what was wrong and what was right. A child or a baby does not know much and are innocent and so Muslim as they cannot decide. Afterwards if you choose to be Muslim then you are Muslim. However, if you go astray then you will be punished. If you reach puberty yet have not come across the religion of Islam and so have no knowledge then it is not your fault and so will not be punished. But it is out duty to find out which religion is right and not blindly inherit religion from our parents.

Comment: You mean to say that you continue to be a Muslim (after presumably being born a Muslim) and you are "rightly guided". Whereas I continue to be a Hindu (after being born a Hindu), and you say I may be going "astray", and therefore deserving of punishment. Is that right?